# IdentityServer4 with Webforms client and token refresh

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, webforms, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have currently implemented IdentityServer4 with OpenIdConnect which is working as required except for how the access_token is refreshed.
Currently the token expires every 5 minutes so when the user submits a form after the token has expired the browser gets redirected to get the new token from the IdentityServer but obviously that causes the user to lose all unsaved data on the form.

Currently I'm struggling to find examples of how I handle this silently (async) in webforms so the user is unaware of the refresh.

Do I have to handle this myself?
Would I handle this in the Global.cs Application_BeginRequest() event or HttpModule
I was looking at this example https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/293622b8438d27f4c9c2574e43fe92a22560ac6b/Clients/src/MvcHybrid/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L46%20
but don't have access to httpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync

Any info on best practices would be great.

Cheers

Comment: We had a very similar situation, and ended up with creating an ajax call, that periodically pings the server (some method requiring authorization). The WebForms app does the backchannel call, and refreshes the token, without submitting a form, and loosing user data

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem ? if so could you please share how you did that @trublesum

Comment: This is not easy in ASP.NET as @m3n7alsnak3 suggests. we just ended up increasing the timeout, there are a few refresh values but I cant remember the one we used.